# What is the meaning of "$m$ has every prime factor of $n$"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, prime-factorization

$m>n$;
given, every prime factor of n is a prime factor of $m$.
Does it even include the repetitive prime factors of $n$?

Example, $n = 12 = 2\cdot2\cdot3$. 
Here it is $2$, $3$ or $2$ ,$2$ ,$3$?

Comment: That depends on definition. Normally it should not count repetitions, but you might define it either way.

Comment: could you provide a link to the paper/book you have read this in. It could be either, but my guess would be $6$ rather than $12$. Also you have $m$ and $n$ switched in the title and question, could you correct this?

Comment: I would say that it means that, for each prime $p$, $p\,|\,n\implies p\,|\,m$.  thus the claim would hold for, say, $m=30,n=12$ even though $4=2^2$ divides $n$ but not $m$.

Comment: If it included repetitive prime factors, then saying "$m$ divides $n$" would be a more established and concise terminology. For that reason I vote that it should not take repeated prime factors into account, as in "$18$ has every prime factor of $12$" is true.

Comment: If two integers have the same prime factors with the same multiplicity, then they are equal up to a sign. So, as a definition, it makes little sense.